# Turn Points with lat and long into polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a CSV file in which each row has a latitude and longitude. Each row is associated to a name of a polygon that the points form together.

How do I upload this file into QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

The below steps were tested in QGIS 3.8 and assumes your coordinates are already correctly ordered:

1. Add CSV table to QGIS
2. Use Processing | Vector Creation | [Create Points layer from table](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreatepointslayerfromtable)
3. Use Processing | Vector Creation | [Points to path](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispointstopath)
4. Use Processing | Vector Geometry | [Lines to polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgislinestopolygons)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do u ensure the "right" **vertices order** in this process ? what is the "id" field you use in the points to path step ?

Comment: That wasn't part of the question, the OP didn't provide enough info to go into any detail.. My answer assumes correct ordering and the "id" field was just an increasing integer.